# Haskell. Where with two definitions

Tags: haskell

Is any way two use 'where' with two or more blocks? Something like this:

```
plus:: Int -> Int -> Int
plus a b = x + y
         where x = f1 a
         where y = f2 b
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Leave off all except the first `where`:

```
plus:: Int -> Int -> Int
plus a b = x + y
         where x = f1 a
               y = f2 b
```

Note that

- the definitions have to line up with each other
- you should indent the definitions using spaces only, not tabs (some text editors don't use the standard tab width for tabs, leading ghc to believe the last line is indented further or less than it actually is; either way causes an error)

Comment: I would like to suggest a short and easy reading about the where syntax: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where.

Comment: A common problem is that the text editor and ghc can disagree on how wide a tab is. Ensure you are indenting both lines with spaces only (not tabs). Otherwise, what error message do you get? Or, in what way does it not work?

Comment: Oh, yes. It was problem with tabs and spaces. Thank you very much

Comment: Not only should you never use tabs, but you should also never use anything except spaces to the left of indentation-sensitive positions. In this example, you should put a newline after `where`. The same argument applies: the editor may use a non-monospace font.

Comment: Rotsor, it may, but it usually doesn't. I try to do what you're suggesting but sometimes - particularly with let - it results in quite a lot of wasted space.